# How does TeX handle cross-platform plain text (source input) line endings?

Tags: cross-platform

I write text, not math. I use Linux, my editor (a human) uses Windows, and does not know any TeX (and does not have TeX). We exchange plain-text utf8 files without any TeX markup.
I usually remember to convert the Linux LF endings to Windows CRLF endings, before I send the file. It is rare for the editor to return anything but CRLF.

I can convert CRLF to LF easily enough. But if I forget to do it, what will happen when I
input that file to my Linux TeX? Is the CR simply ignored (ideally)? I did not see it in the catcode table. Or does the CR have consequences?

I tried a few test cases, without visible problem, but that does not mean there are no larger issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

web2c based implementations take `U+000A`, `U+000D` and `U+000DU+000A` pairs as a line end on all platforms.

Even if the file is mixed format with different conventions within the same file it makes no difference each of those sequences is treated as line end, any space `U+0020` before that are stripped and the end of line is marked with the current `\endlinechar` (if that is a valid character code)

Comment: Thanks! Knowing that the goodness is built-in, not hacked, is comforting.